# decrease the spacing in HTML-CSS

Tags: html, css

I want some space between the text in class footer and class footer2 shown below

To do so i added padding bottom to the above footer and padding top to the footer2 below

I got a very large space using 1px in both paddings .. how can I decrease it without making a blank space between the 2 footers' brown backgrounds?

try it for better illustration .. thanks

```
.footer { 
    font-style: italic; 
    font-family: arial;  
    font-size: 10pt;  
    text-align: center;  
    background-color: #996633;  
    padding-top: 1px;  
    padding-right: 50px;  
    padding-bottom: 1px;  
    padding-left: 50px; 
}

.footer2 {  
    font-style: italic;  
    font-family: arial;  
    font-size:10pt;  
    text-align:center;  
    background-color: #996633;  
    padding-top: 1px;  
    padding-right: 50px;  
    padding-bottom: 1px; 
    padding-left: 50px;
}

<div class="footer">
    <pre>
        <em>23 Pine Road</em>
        <em>Nottingham, NGI 5YU</em>
        <em>0115 9324567</em>
    </pre>
</div>

<div class="footer2">
    <pre>
        <em>Copyright &copy 2011 Jake's Coffee House</em>
        <a href="http://www.hotmail.com" > jake@jcoffee.com </a>
    </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Like @Huangism mentioned, the `<pre />` tag is automatically adding your margin. Why not just use a `<div />` tag instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pre` tag has natural margin so that's why you are seeing the white space. Just set margin to 0 for `pre`

```
pre { margin: 0; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s8uhpfc8/

Feel free to adjust the padding top/bottom for the 2 footer classes, but the margin on `pre` is the cause for the white space.

Answer (score 0):

Here are many possible solutions:

1. Remove the margin for the `div`

   - for the first `div`

     ```
     margin-bottom: -1cm;
     ```

   or

   - for the second `div`:

     ```
     margin-top: -30px;
     ```
2. Mark `pre` as `inline`:

   ```
   pre {
       display: inline;
   }
   ```
3. See the other posts that set the `margin` for `pre`

Comment: Not that I care who gets the check mark but this is not the root of the issue

Comment: This is more of a hack fix since the issue is caused by the default margin on the `pre`. I don't care which way the OP uses in his code but this doesn't really educate the OP as to what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

```
pre { 
   margin: 0px;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This will remove the unwanted space between your footers. You can then adjust the spacing to your liking with "padding" or "margin".

Comment: I see @Huangism got there a few minutes before me...

Do it as Huangism suggests to reduce the space, or add the "white-space" selector to remove all space.